# How to make the ubuntu internet symbol look like its disabled, even though it's not

Tags: display, settings

I want to make it look like that the internet is disconnected even though it is connected by making the internet/wifi symbol on the Ubuntu OS look like it's currently disconnected from the internet. The LAN cable will be connected at all times but I want it to pretend that nothing is connected and make sure that the network is working perfectly

Comment: It depends on your icons theme. The icons for the network app are stored somewhere under `/usr/share/icons/`. Find the right one, e.g. `network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg`, back them all up, and copy `network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg` over all the status icon files you want to change.

Comment: @jos ok ill check on that but, what do i do after finding that? I dont know how to change that and what do i change it to?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you have several files containing different icons, with different names, for different statuses of your network. To do what you want, you need copies of the same icon (e.g. `network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg`) with different names.

This is that icon (it's a bit vague because I can't upload `svg` images):

[image]

If you want a different icon to be displayed at all times, replace `network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg` in the following by the filename of that icon.

The following will work, but please, don't blindly copy and paste `bash` scripts without knowing what you are doing. And anyway you need to locate the icons first: that depends on which `icon theme` you are currently using. I use the `Yaru` icon theme so in my case, the icons are located in `/usr/share/icons/Yaru/scalable/status/`.

```
# first, backup the icons. Create a backup directory:
mkdir ~/icons-backup

# navigate to the icons directory within your theme
cd /usr/share/icons/...path to your icons/

# move the wired and wireless network icons over to the backup directory (needs sudo)
# this will move all icon files starting with "network-wire" 
sudo mv network-wire*.svg ~/icons-backup

# copy the real "disconnected" icon back to the icons folder
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg .

# copy the disconnected icon back several times using different names
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wired-acquiring-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wired-disconnected-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wired-no-route-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wired-offline-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-acquiring-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-connected-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-disabled-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-encrypted-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-hardware-disabled-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-hotspot-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-offline-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-signal-excellent-secure-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-signal-excellent-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-signal-good-secure-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-signal-good-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-signal-none-secure-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-signal-none-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-signal-ok-secure-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-signal-ok-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-signal-weak-secure-symbolic.svg
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/network-wireless-no-route-symbolic.svg ./network-wireless-signal-weak-symbolic.svg
```

At this point you have messed up the icons to the effect that whatever the network status, all icon files will contain the same icon, so the `no route` icon will be displayed at all times. I can't imagine why you would want this, but there you go.

If you want to restore the original situation, do

```
sudo cp ~/icons-backup/* /usr/share/icons/...path to your icons/
```